# How I can Do a transaction rollback and commit at the time of import

Tags: django, database, postgresql, python-2.7, transactions

The code given below is the program to import data into my django model,
actually what this program does is it read the file and it import each line from the file to the django model, here may be 1000 files will be there,there will be some error in some file and the program will catch the exception if the file have any type of error and log it, But what i need is to rollback the entire transaction from one file which throws an error.I want to do this in postgres

```
def impSecOrdr_File(self,path):
    lines=1
    try:
        fromFile=open(path)
        for eachLine in fromFile:
            obj = SecOrdr_File()
            if lines!=1:
                fieldsInline = eachLine.split(",")
                obj.dates =  dates
                obj.column1 = fieldsInline[0].strip()
                obj.column2 = fieldsInline[1].strip()
                obj.column3 = float(fieldsInline[2].strip())
                obj.column4 = float(fieldsInline[3].strip())
                obj.save()
            lines+=1
    except BaseException as e:
        transaction.rollback()
        logging.info('\tError in importing %s line %d : %s' % (path, lines, e.__str__()))
    else:
        try:
            logging.info("\tImported %s, %d lines" % (path, lines))
        except Exception as e:
            logging.info(e)
```

Is there any way to do that. I went through the django transaction document and I tried Some of these but it is not working.. Can any one help me please

Comment: Remember mysql with isam files don't suports transactions. What dbms and storage system are you using?

Comment: I am not using mysql I am using sqlite3

Comment: Sqlite supports acid tx. Please arrange your code in your question, keep it simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the obj into a list use a try statement if all the transaction passes the save the transactions

```
lis =[]
try:
   #your code
   lis.append(obj) #instead of obj.save()
except:
   #catch the error and transaction get cancelled
else:
    k=len(lis)
    for i in range(k):
         lis[i].save()
```

I will suggest you to use postgresSQL instead of sqlite